# Sending java JSONobject to javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, json

Passing a JSONobject in java to a javascript function

```
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {
                json.put("Colour", spinnerText1);
                json.put("Gender", spinnerText2);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
```

and

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:updateJSON('User36'" + ",'" +
incident + "'," +
latitude + "," +
longitude + ",\"" +
"asdf" + "\")");
```

The above file sends to the javascript file correctly. I want to replace "asdf" with a JSONobject named json = {"Colour":"White","Gender":"Male"}

Using json.toString() does not work (likely due to the apostrophes). I can't get \" to work either. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

what you do is sending a String. One thing you can do is to transform the JSON to a string

```
final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
    json.put("Colour", spinnerText1);
    json.put("Gender", spinnerText2);
} catch (JSONException e) {...}
```

perhaps you have a look at the class documentation in java (toString is available too)
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject.html

```
webview.loadUrl(
  "javascript:updateJSON(
    'User36'" + ",'" +
    incident + "'," +
    latitude + "," +
    longitude + ",\"" +
    json.toString() + "\"
  )"
);
```

perhaps its better too, to build a complete object with username and the other properties and send this directly to the function.

Comment: You are confusing Java and JS I think. The above question is in Java. var and JSON.parse() are not Java

Comment: yes first i have not seen it's java ;)  i edited it. the toString function is what you need

Comment: I tried this and it won't work. The json {"Colour":"White","Gender":"Male"} includes apostrophes and commas which hinder it being sent in one String. Even  "{\"Colour\":"White\",\"Gender\":\"Male\"}" doesn't work

Comment: ``"'" + "{\"Colour\":"White\",\"Gender\":\"Male\"}" + "'"`` woks this?

Answer (score 0):

Need to replace the commas in json as follows

```
        final String json1 = json.toString();
        final String json2 = json1.replace("\"","\\");
        Log.e("JSON data",json2);
```

then

```
                    webview.loadUrl("javascript:updateJSON('User36'" + ",'" +
                            incident + "'," +
                            latitude + "," +
                            longitude + ",\"" +
                            json2 + "\")");
```